# Prevent text truncation in Carto map

Tags: carto

Our map (not publicly visible, sorry) shows owner names and property boundaries.  Sometimes the names are truncated about a vertical line, as in these examples.  The first example also shows one name spans the vertical line.

[image: map 1]

[image: map 2]

I'm wondering if the text is only laid over a tile if a small circle around the centre point happens to fall on the tile.  In the case of *Kauri Glen Limited* in the first example, perhaps the circle falls onto two tiles.  Pure guesswork.

Can anyone explain definitively what's going on, and provide a way to prevent the truncation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If some of your labels have words that appear cut off at the tile edges, the buffer area in your map is too small. In [this section](https://carto.com/docs/faqs/maps#why-are-my-map-labels-cut-off) of the CARTO documentation you can find how to solve the problem.

Comment: I'm wondering if a large `buffer-size` might affect performance (having to handle items which are actually off the edge of the tile, but whose buffer falls on the tile)?  Are there any other docs covering the `buffer-size` property?